# Get the entry in a grid row where the button was pressed

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a Grid with 4 columns (Entry, button, button, switch), and x rows. The rows gets created by the program. Now I want to switch some properties from the Entry and the Switch up / down to the next or previous Entry / Switch. This should happen by clicking by the buttons. First button up, second down. But I dont know how to get the entry and switch at that row where the buttons was pressed.

Its for an Android /iOS Game and I want that User can Switch their Entries (they are for their names) up or down, because the program later is working clockwise so the users should enter their names like it too. I started trying to get the buttons in one specific row:

```
buttons = UserGrid.Children.Cast<Button>().Where(c => Grid.GetRow(c) == 2).ToArray(); // In this case it was row2


roundedentrylist.Add(new RoundedEntry()
            {
                Placeholder = "Spieler " + row,
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Entry)),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            });

            switchlist.Add(new Switch()
            {
                IsToggled = false,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End
            });

            buttonUpList.Add(new Button()
            {
                Text = "↑",
                CornerRadius = 8,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Button))
            });

            buttonDownList.Add(new Button()
            {
                Text = "↓",
                CornerRadius = 8,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Button))
            });

a bit later im adding them to my Grid:

UserGrid.Children.Add(roundedentrylist[entriesCounter], 0, row);
UserGrid.Children.Add(buttonUpList[entriesCounter], 1, row);
UserGrid.Children.Add(buttonDownList[entriesCounter], 2, row);
UserGrid.Children.Add(switches[entriesCounter], 3, row);

Now to the Problem: Im trying to add for all buttonDown or buttonUp a function which switches the properties to the next or previous.

For this I started trying the following:


for (int i = 0; i < buttonDownList.Count; i++)
            {
                buttonDownList[i].Clicked += async delegate
                {
                    buttons = UserGrid.Children.Cast<Button>().Where(c => Grid.GetRow(c) == i).ToArray(); // i is the row
                    foreach (var item in buttons)
                    {
                        if (item.Id == buttonDownList[i].Id)
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Button", "Found", "yay");
                        }

                    }
                    //buttons = UserGrid.Children.Cast<Button>().Where(f => Grid.GetRow(f) == 2).ToArray();
                    //roundedEntries = UserGrid.Children.Cast<RoundedEntry>().Where(f => Grid.GetRow(f) == 2).ToArray();
                };
            }
```

Im sorry for the formatting. Some Code doesnt get formatted as code. Im new at this page. I hope you can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a command parameter through the click event of the button.

```
<Button Clicked="btn_clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding param}"/>
```

and then catch that parameter like below.

```
 var button = (Button)sender;
 var param = (object)button.CommandParameter;
```

based on the parameter you can do whatever the thing you want.